# Why is www. working but no-www is not?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, no-www

Right now my site runs on `http://www.example.com` but I need to run that without www also i.e `example.com`

***Can some body tell me here that how can i do that?***

Comment: Why do you need this? Most of the  I have read recommend the opposite, redirecting non-www visitors to www.

Comment: From SEO point of view, any one of them ie either www -> non www or vice versa is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple using `.htaccess` file, simply add:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Simply place `.htaccess` file on the root folder/directory.